# Shishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sancheriv's army, when he attempted to conquer Yerushalayim, consisted of 260 myriad thousand (2.6 billion!) soldiers "minus one" - about which Abaye is uncertain whether this means one myriad (in which case this would have been a good answer for 259), one thousand, one hundred, or one individual.

(Sanhedrin 95b)

Answer (score 1):

In 1908, approximately 260,000 school-age Jewish kids in America received no formal Jewish education at all. Source: [Samson Benderly](http://www.jewishideasdaily.com/content/module/2011/6/22/main-feature/1/hebrew-school/f), as [quoted in *Jewish Philanthropy*, a 1917 book by Boris D. Bogen](http://books.google.com/books?id=w01HAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA217&dq=sixty).

Answer (score 1):

Volume 1 of [one edition of שו״ת רש״י](http://hebrewbooks.org/1734) has 260 responsa.